# puppeteer screen shot is broken on github action

Tags: loops, github, puppeteer, element, screenshot

Using the puppeeteer to compare the image between origin and new one.

using the selector.

env is github action.
take a screen shot and compare it with origin images.
using the puppeteer version : 19.

```
`await puppeteer.launch({
args: [
'--disable-gpu',
'--disable-gpu-compositing',
'--disable-gpu-rasterization',
'--single-process',
'--ignore-certifacate-errors',
'--start-maximized',
'--no-sandbox',
'--enable-features=NetworkService'
],
  defaultviewport: null,
  headless: true,
  isMobile: true
});`


`let components = await this.page.$$(selector);

for(const [index, component] of components.entries()) {

try {
    await component.screenshot({path: filepath, captureBeyondViewport: false});
} catch (e) {

}
```

}`

there are 30 components. and it take a screenshot using loop.
But sometimes the screenshot of component is broken.
it is not expanded fully -> height is short than origin size.
it doesn't draw all items in component etc. -> it have to draw 1,2,3. but it just capture after drawing 1,2. so it doesn't capture 3.

as a result, it take a screenshot before drawing all items in each component.randomly.

all components screen host are captured correctly.
local pc evn, there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my library that I wrote to stabilize some puppeteer functions (and also - screenshots).

Example:
https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/src/element/baseDrivers/elementBaseDriver.ts#L230C1-L230C1

You can try this code

```js
import { waitForElementPositionToBeStale } from 'bubanai-ng';

let components = await this.page.$$(selector); // in my lib that action equals await getElements(page, selector);

for(const [index, component] of components.entries()) {

    await waitForElementPositionToBeStale(page, component);
    await component.screenshot({path: filepath, captureBeyondViewport: false});
    }
```

Or you can not to import library and just try to use this function:

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/src/element/waits/waitForElementPositionToBeStale.ts